# What is the meaning of 2D stride in convolution?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, stride

I know what meaning stride has when it is just an integer number (by which step you should apply filter to image). But what about `(1, 1)` or even more dimensional stride?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *stride* defines how the filter is moved along the input image (tensor). Nothing stops you from striding along different axes differently, e.g., `stride=[1, 2]` means move 1px at a time along 0 axis, and 2px at a time along 1 axis. This particular combination isn't common, but possible.

Tensorflow API goes even further and allows custom striding for all axes of the 4D input tensor (see [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d)). Using this API it's not uncommon to set `strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]`, which makes perfect sense: it should process each image (the first `1`) and each input channel (the last `1`), but apply `2x2` striding of the spatial dimensions. As far as the convolution is concerned, the operation is *applicable* for any `strides` array, however not values are equally useful.

Highly recommend [this CS231n tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) for more detail on this.